# What are the differences between the Joomla! CMS, the Joomla! Platform and the Joomla! Framework?

Tags: cms, joomla-framework-1.x

Many of us have come to understand Joomla! to refer to a specific software we use, yet there are 3 different types of software available from Joomla!

These are:

1) The Joomla! CMS;

2) The Joomla! Platform; and

3) The Joomla! Framework.

What are the differences?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The **Joomla! CMS** is the product you likely know and use. It's the Content Management System which powers many sites. Usually when talking about Joomla!, we just mean the CMS.
Official site: http://www.joomla.org/

The **Joomla! Platform** is the old underlying code which powers the CMS. It used to be a separated project but was merged back into the CMS. The platform no longer exists as an own project

The **Joomla! Framework** is a rather new project. It's meant as a framework to power various standalone applications. It's based on the CMS code, but was modernised and improved a lot. Currently, the CMS only uses a few classes from the framework, but that is likely to raise over the time. There are also other applications like JIssues which are built on this framework.
Official site: http://framework.joomla.org/

Comment: I think that this answer would benefit from some links. Maybe the places to download the different applications?

Comment: Added links to the official sites where one finds more informations.
Obviously there is no such link for the platform :)

Answer (score 7):

@Bakual did a good job of explaining it, but I just wanted to add that a big purpose of the Framework is to improve practices for everyone who develops extensions for the CMS. It follows modern practices and makes it easier to write clean, testable code. I say this from the standpoint as a big proponent of the Framework (I've contributed heavily) and from the fact that I use the Joomla! CMS every day at work, and I want to make that easier.

The Framework is the future!