# Why using Joomla! Framework?

Tags: joomla-framework-1.x

What are the reasons for choosing **`Joomla! Framework`** for a web application instead of using `Zend Framework 2`, `CodeIgniter`, `Laravel` etc?

Will its popularity increase sufficiently and will Joomla! site developers migrate from the [cms](/questions/tagged/cms) to the [joomla-framework](/questions/tagged/joomla-framework) soon?

Answer (score 4):

The CMS provides a lot of chrome, features and functionality that are not in platform (eg. control panel, user management, etc.).

The Framework includes all the underlying structure including database functions, string manipulations, etc. but it isn't a CMS. (According to the Framework project, the Joomla CMS will be refactored to use the Framework functions, but currently uses only a small set).

So if you want a CMS, there's no reason to migrate to the framework (unless you want to re-invent the wheel). If you want to build a web app, web services or command line application using proven functionality, you can use the Framework to provide lots of convenience and utility functions, much like Zend.

Here's a thread with more information: [What are the differences between the Joomla! CMS, the Joomla! Platform and the Joomla! Framework?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-are-the-differences-between-the-joomla-cms-the-joomla-platform-and-the-j?rq=1)

Comment: Actually most of the sites (and not blogs) do not need a CMS. They have a few static pages like `About Us` etc. so you need no article nor category. If a developer choose the J! Framework and writes a user management component for a project, he/she can reuse it in other projects. Also you can amend the current user component of the CMS and implement it in the framework.

Comment: @Fari-- if you wanted a simple site with static pages it'd be smarter to use jekyll or even AmazonS3. No need for CMS or Framework in that case, and no need for user management.

Comment: Consider a large site with a few static pages. For example a Real Estate website which has "About Us" and "TOS" static pages plus 1 million "For Sale" dynamic pages.

Comment: I'd use IProperty. Then you get the benefit of a pre-made component as well as the option to add dozens of other components like newsletters that may be useful!

Comment: I want to think more about the Framework in this thread. We know that the performance is important for mid-size and large projects. So I prefer to use a Framework. A component/package like IProperty can be written in the Framework. For a large project it is worth to create even an admin CP, etc. from scratch.